# How is jQuery documentation generated

Tags: jquery

I am looking at the [source code of jQuery in subversion](http://dev.jquery.com/browser/tags/1.3.2) . What I would like to know is how jQuery docuemtation is generated since I do not see any documentation in the source code. Unlike Java/Ruby there is no documentation done when a method is defined. So where is the repository for the jQuery documentation in the svn ?

I personally use [this](http://view.jquery.com/trunk/tools/api-browser/) site to browse the jQuery methods.

Please note that my question is not about how to get documentation. I am curious about how the documentation is generated and where is the repository for that.

I would like to embed the documentation in a fun personal project and hence the question.

Answer (score 1):

You say "Unlike Java/Ruby there is no documentation done when a method is defined." It appears that the [src/](http://dev.jquery.com/browser/tags/1.3.2/src) tree is where the real source code is generated, then jQuery is built from that.

Now, as to the documentation (your actual question!), it looks what you want is the API Reference file on the [Downloading jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery): http://dev.jquery.com/view/trunk/tools/api-browser/jquery-api-browser.zip

It looks like that contains the link you mentioned. I also like [api.jquery.com](http://api.jquery.com/) and before it went out of date, [www.visualjquery.com](http://www.visualjquery.com/)

Comment: Does that mean if a person adds a new method called foo to jQuery then that person should go and edit jquery-api-browser.zip to add the description about this newly added method called 'foo'?.

Comment: Raj, I don't know. You'd have to contact the maintainers of the code with regards to that.

Answer (score 0):

[This link](http://jquery14.com/pre-release-1/new-jquery-api-site) provides some insight on the new api.jquery.com site. Apparently the backend is written in WordPress and a [XML dump](http://api.jquery.com/api/) is provided for the complete documentation. I guess the documentation can only be edited and improved by people that have a api.jquery.com WordPress account.